# How to remove extra occurrences of a letter in a string?

Tags: javascript

Using Javascript is there a way to remove extra occurrences of a specific letter in a string?

For example:

```js
remove_extra('a', 'caaaat')
//=> 'cat'
```

I know there must be a brute force way to do something like this but is there an elegant way?  I'm not sure how to approach this algorithm.

Comment: only `'a'` or any extra copies?

Comment: @Nina Scholz The first 'a' can stay but all additional 'a' removed.  It could be any letter I'm just using 'a' as an example.

Comment: have you tried anything? what does not work?

Comment: @NinaScholz No, I've thought about this and hit a block.  Using Regex it's easy enough to remove every letter of a specific type.  Unfortunately I can't see a clever way to remove every letter after the first other than using brute force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I misunderstood your question.

To only keep one instance of specified char:

```js
function onlyOneCharOf(string, pattern) {
  let first = true;
  //if (pattern.length !==1) throw Error("Expected one character");
  pattern=pattern.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'); //escape RegEx special chars
  return string.replace(new RegExp(pattern, "g"), value => {
    if (first) {
      first = false;
      return value;
    }
    return "";
  });
}

console.log(onlyOneCharOf("zzzzzaaabbbbcccc", "a"));
```

Note: the pattern given to the function is used to create a RegEx. Since some characters are *special characters*, those characters must be escaped. I updated the function to do that for you. You might also want to check the length, but the length might be larger than 1 for some unicode code points.

---

If you only want any character to appear once, you can use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```js
function unique(string) {
  return Array.from(new Set(string.split(''))).join('');
}
console.log(unique("caaaat"));
```

A value in a *Set* may only occur once.

Comment: Set's are great but they have a similar problem to the Regex method.  Set's will only contain a given value once.  But what if every value should be able to repeat but 1.  For example unlimited "b", "c", "d" but only 1 "a".  I wonder if the only way to solve this is a simple loop with an if/then. Once again no idea why this question is getting thumbs down.

Comment: @myNewAccount Sorry, misunderstood what you wanted. See updated answer.

Comment: `.replace()` combined with `Regex`.  I was thinking of `.map`, `.reduce` etc. etc. and a bunch of other hard ways to approach this.  Your way was perfect.

Comment: @myNewAccount See updated answer for special characters.

Answer (score 3):

you can do this with regex:

```
var test = "aaabbbccc";
console.log(test.replace(/(.)(?=.*\1)/g, "")); //would print abc
var test2 = "caaaaat";
console.log(test2.replace(/(.)(?=.*\1)/g, "")); //would print cat
```

Comment: That's brilliant!  I didn't think this could be done with straight regex.  But what if I needed this to apply to a single letter like 'a' instead of all letters?  BTW I have no idea why this question is getting thumbs down.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.from` to explode a string:

```js
Array.from('caaaat');
//=> ["c", "a", "a", "a", "a", "t"]
```

You can then use `Array#filter` to keep everything that is neither "a" nor the first occurrence of "a":

```js
Array.from('caaaat').filter((x, i, xs) => x !== 'a' || xs.indexOf(x) === i).join('');
//=> "cat"
```

*(I leave it to you as an exercise to put this into a reusable function.)*

---

Just be aware that if you choose to interpret `char` as a regular expression without validating it first, you may have unexpected results:

```js
function onlyOneCharOf(string, char) {
  let first = true;
  return string.replace(new RegExp(char, "g"), value => {
    if (first) {
      first = false;
      return value;
    }
    return "";
  });
}

onlyOneCharOf('caaat', '.');
//=> "c"

onlyOneCharOf('caaat', '?');
//=> SyntaxError
```